# How open existing PyDev project?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

Experienced Programmer, but new to Python. Using OsGeoLive and PyDev on Eclipse.

A few weeks ago I started a new project in PyDev (my first one).  I set the project aside and am only now coming back to it.  But when I open Eclipse, I do not see any way to open the project I started.  There is no Recent Projects on the File Menu, File > Import does not seem to be what I need.  The Project menu has an Open Project item, but it is deactivated.  When I open the project's .xml file from Eclipse, it opens it as an editable XML file.

How do I open an existing PyDev project, or alternately, how do I trouble shoot PyDev losing track of the directory structure?

Comment: welcome to eclipse + pydev .... after struggling through this type of problem several times I caved and went with pycharm ... I doubt ill ever go back (I even like it enough to pay for the comercial version) ...

Comment: Try creating a new project, and see whether you can find that.

Comment: Peter Wood, I did that already.  It created the new project right next to the old one.

Comment: How did you "set it aside"?  Are you in the right view (perspective)?  Check to the top-right corner - it may have reverted to the Java perspective.  Otherwise, more detail is needed - I don't think I can recall ever "losing" a project in Eclipse with PyDev.  Also, under Import do you not find "Existing project into workspace" or does it not work somehow?

Comment: Joran Beasley.  Yes, I think yours is the best answer.  If you want to make it a formal answer, I will select it.

Comment: g.d.d.c., the Perspective is PyDev.  I confirmed it just now.  Yes, I attempted Existing project into workspace.  I chose my project root folder, which it selected.  I clicked the Wizard's "Finish" button, but nothing seemed to happen.  Nothing appear in PyDev Package Explorer.  Project > Open Project is still deactivated.  Thanks for your effort to help.  I just don't have time to spend on this when there are so many other alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Locate the Package Explorer window and see if there any project folders in there. You also have the option to see "Working Sets", which are convenient to create projects distributed through several folders. Just to make sure, check out if you see something like this (You can display Projects with the prompted submenu):

[image]

If you don't see anything there, perhaps your project folder is missing an **init**.py file, in order to be recognized as a package, which is a general Python standard.

Sorry if this doesn't help much, I cannot leave comments yet.

Comment: I switched to PyCharm and found that it has no problem finding the project and opening it.